# Multi module Android project does not build on Jitpack

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, multi-module, jitpack

I have a multi-module library that I need to publish to Jitpack.io but the problem is that only one module got recognized by consumer apps, and it seems that the other module is not built correctly although when I check Jitpack build log, everything looks good to me.
While debugging I tried to build only the module that is not seen by the consumer apps but Jitpack build did not trigger at all.

Is there anything I'm missing ?
Thanks in advance.